# MongoDB aggregate compare with previous document

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, tornado-motor

I have this query in Motor:

```
history = yield self.db.stat.aggregate([
        {'$match': {'user_id': user.get('uid')}},
        {'$sort': {'date_time': -1}},
        {'$project': {'user_id': 1, 'cat_id': 1, 'doc_id': 1, 'date_time': 1}},
        {'$group': {
            '_id': '$user_id',
            'info': {'$push': {'doc': '$doc_id', 'date': '$date_time', 'cat': '$cat_id'}},
            'total': {'$sum': 1}
        }},
        {'$unwind': '$info'},
    ])
```

Documents in `stat` collection look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5788fa45bc54f428d8e77903"),
    "vrr_id" : 2,
    "date_time" : ISODate("2016-07-15T14:59:17.411Z"),
    "ip" : "10.79.0.230",
    "cat_id" : "rsl01",
    "vrr_group" : ObjectId("55f6d1b5aaab934a00bae1a4"),
    "col" : [ 
        "dledu"
    ],
    "vrr_type" : "TH",
    "doc_type" : "local",
    "user_id" : "696230",
    "page" : null,
    "method" : "OpenView",
    "branch" : 9,
    "sc" : 200,
    "doc_id" : "004894802",
    "spec" : 0
}

/* 40 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5788fa45bc54f428d8e77904"),
    "vrr_id" : 2,
    "date_time" : ISODate("2016-07-15T14:59:17.500Z"),
    "ip" : "10.79.0.230",
    "cat_id" : "rsl01",
    "vrr_group" : ObjectId("55f6d1b5aaab934a00bae1a4"),
    "col" : [ 
        "autoref"
    ],
    "vrr_type" : "TH",
    "doc_type" : "open",
    "user_id" : "696230",
    "page" : null,
    "method" : "OpenView",
    "branch" : 9,
    "sc" : 200,
    "doc_id" : "000000002",
    "spec" : "07"
}
```

I want to compare `date_time` field with `date_time` from previous document and if they are not equal (or not in timedelta within 5 seconds), include it in result.

Filtering this in Python was easy, is it possible in Mongo? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you include some example documents from the "stat" collection I can give a more reliable answer. But with the information you've provided, I can guess. Add a stage something like:

```
{'$group': {'_id': '$info.date', 'info': {'$first': '$info'}}}
```

That gives you each document in the result list that has a distinct "date" from the previous document.

That said, if all you need is a distinct list of dates, this is simpler and faster:

```
db.stats.distinct("date_time")
```

Comment: Updated my question and noticed, that in fact my `date_time` is always not equal, because of microseconds. Is there a way to get one value, that is in timedelta within 5 second?

Comment: @asyndrige I am also wondering how to do this. Found any solution in the meantime?